¿Por qué el precompilador SQL no puede hacer uso de un registro insertado al fuente mediante un Copy en un programa Cobol en IBM I?
Tengo un error al compilar un programa cobol en IBM I ¿Qué opciones de compilación se debe establecer para que el precompilador SQL no marque error por no encontrar la definición de un registro extraído de un COPY?
Algunos escenarios a consideran son los siguientes:

Si coloco la definición del registro directamente en el código (removiendo el COPY) el programa compila y trabaja bien.

Si quito la sentencia SQL, el compilador me trae el contenido del COPY y compila bien, pero, al no tener la sentencia SQL el programa no hace lo que debe hacer.

El registro está bien definido ya que al insertar la declaración de registro directamente en el código este trabaja bien con la sentencia SQL por lo tanto la cantidad de campo y tipos de datos son correctas.


Agradezco me puedan ayudar brindándome información o guías para entender la sincronización de las opciones de compilación o una guía para saber como el precompilador SQL está tratando las variables.

Ya lo resolví aunque cambie el enfoque, llegando al resultado esperado, mantuve el fuente del cual hacía uso por medio del copy solo que lo agregué con "SQL NCLUDE". Tuve varios problemas para que el compilador lo encontrara según algunas documentaciones que encontré podía indicar la dirección de los archivos a agregar por medio de "SQL INCLUDE"  mediante el parámetro INCDIR pero, al agregar la ruta este marcaba un error de congruencia con el parámetro SRCFILE por lo tanto dejé el fuente al cual necesitaba hacer el copy en la misma ubicación donde tenía el fuente principal a compilar, compiló bien y me permite trabajar con las definiciones de campos sin hacer uso del  "OF TABLA" al agregar la definición del registro con "SQL INCLUDE" el precompilador SQL logra trabajar con las variables tal cual hubiera definido el registro en el fuente principal a compilar, al tener esta definición de registro aislada puedo ahorrar tiempo definiendo el registro en cada programa que lo requiera.
Seguí el enfoque de DCLGEN, lo maneje tal cual se agregaría SQLCA.
